# Android SDK tools in Ubuntu doesn't read Nexus 7 in recovery mode (Possible udev rules issue)

Tags: udev, nexus-7, recovery-mode, adb, android-sdk

so I'm trying to push a ROM in my bricked Nexus 7 through adb in Ubuntu. The problem is that, when I plug it in recovery mode to my laptop, and run

> adb devices

the system doesn't find my Nexus 7. Connecting my Moto E in recovery and running the command instead works.
On the mount options of TWRP recovery I tried to disable MTP, but the outcome doesn't change.

I've done some research on the web and it appears that this is a common problem for this device due to missing drivers. Indeed Windows users can easily find driver bundles that apparently fix this issue, but you don't have this option for Linux.

So, IF the assumption is correct, how can I add these drivers to my android sdk tools for Linux, and finally be able to read the laptop while in recovery mode?
Cheers.

P.S: I know that you are not supposed to install any particular drivers to run Android sdk on Linux, but if we rule this out then, why it can't recognize my Nexus 7?

Comment: OK due update... after further research I came to the realization that is not about drivers (which is a Windows issue), but missing udev rules to identify the USB configuration of the device.

Comment: Nothing I could do so far... I've added manually the udev rule following faithfully this guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK, but no luck. On SDK manager I notice that on "Google USB drivers" says "not compatible with linux".  I don't think it has really to do with this,  but at this stage I'm out of sorts. Looking how many people encounter similar issues with this device, I'd say there's something not quite right with the compatibility with ADB of this model. I put the link anyway in case it can help someone else.